# (Un)Register BroadastReceiver programmatically?

Tags: android, flutter, service

I'm developing a Flutter plugin that given the user the possibility to listen to Phone State even when the app is in background / closed. The problem here is that I want to be able to enable / disable this service programatically, right now I have on my `AndroidManifest.xml` the following `receiver`:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallerPhoneServiceReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And it works perfectly, my `dart` code is called on the background with no problems, now I want to disable this `receiver` whenever the user decides that it doesn't want to listen for this events anymore, by googling a bit I found the `registerReceiver` and `unregisterReceiver` that apparently do what I need, but it appears that `unregisterReceiver` works only when called with the same object was passed to the `registerReceiver` as argument, basically it works as long as the app stays opened, but how could I unregister if the user decides to close the app and come back to deactivate the events? Even when the user deactivate by itself, I wanna be able to call this method in case of a logout.

I've seen a few examples that says to use `sharedPreferences` and save whether the service is `ON/OFF` and then decide if call or not the `dart` code, but my service would still remaing active doing nothing but active, and this may consume battery, it doesn't appear to be a good solution, what could I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PackageManager` to enable or disable `BroadcastReceiver` defined in `AndroidManifest` file. Refer to the code below:

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, CallerPhoneServiceReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, 
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

You can use `PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED` to disable a component and `PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED` for enable a component.